# Python websocket context manager with a while True in body, closing connection

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

From the next test code

```
    async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"

    while True:
        async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
            await ws.send("Test \n")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(hello())
```

This code performs the desired behavior of sending a message each second,
yet it seems that it could be more efficient by doing the changes shown below:

```
    async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"

    
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
        while True:
            await ws.send("Test \n")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(hello())
```

But, in this second approach, the context manager exits and outputs the next exception:

```
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
    websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), no reason
```

Why is the context manager closing the connection if the body is properly indented within the context manager?

Comment: please, provide fully working code with imports and correct indentation so the error wouldb be reproducible by us

Comment: please also provide full error trace, so it would be clear which lines causes the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably following `websockets` library [example](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#basic-example).

As written in the example:

> On the server side, websockets executes the handler coroutine hello
> once for each WebSocket connection. It closes the connection when the
> handler coroutine returns.

Below is Websockets server from the example:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f"> {greeting}")

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

And Websockets client modified to use `while True` loop:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        while True:
            print(websocket.closed)
            await websocket.send("Test")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

        print(f"> {name}")

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting}")


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Running the server and then the client provides the following output:

In server:

```
< Test
> Hello Test!
```

In client:

```
What's your name? hi
False
True
...
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), no reason
```

In the first case you presented, the code creates websocket connection every  loop iteration. Whereas in the second, the code reuses the connection which is closed by the server after handling as the documentation states. You can see that the `websocket` connection is closed by inspecting `websocket.closed` field.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the issue towards the server side, I was only looking at the client side thinking the issue was there, the solution for constantly receiving would suffice with a While True loop inside the callback.